# Criteria query looking for rows using a specific subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, table-per-subclass

I'll start with a sanitized example.

In my system, I've got the class Car. Car has a number of fields, among which is the gearShift instance of class GearShift.

```
public class Car {
    private GearShift gearShift;

    // Snip
}
```

GearShift is an abstract class, from which AutomaticShift and StickShift inherit. This is mapped in Hibernate as table-per-subclass.

Now, say I want to get the cars with automatic gear shifts. I'd prefer doing this through Hibernate criteria, so I'm imagining an "ofType" restriction I can add, like shown below.

```
getSession().createCriteria(Car.class)
    .add(Restrictions.ofType(AutomaticShift.class)
    .list();
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: How is your mapping? Do you use a discriminator?

Comment: Why using HQL is not an option? Criteria API does not expose full Hibernate functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**OLD:**

How about this?

```
getSession().createCriteria(AutomaticShift.class).list()
```

**EDIT:**

This should do the trick;

```
getSession().createCriteria(Car.class).createAlias("gearShift", "gs").add(Restrictions.eq("gs.class", AutomaticShift.class)).list();
```

Comment: That would just return a list of automatic gears. -1 for this

Comment: @RaulGogo: That's what I though he wanted to do :S Do you understand different?

Comment: He wants a list of **cars** with automatic gears.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it sounds a little like an overhead, but you could do it in 2 steps:

1. Retrieve all the ids of the Automatic Gears:

   ```
   List<Long> automaticGearIds = getSession().createCriteria(AutomaticShift.class)
                                           .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Property.forName("id")))
                                           .list();
   ```
2. Get all the cars with automatic gears:

   ```
   return getSession().createCriteria(Car.class).add(Restrictions.in("gearShift.id", automaticGearIds)).list();
   ```

Comment: Using Restrictions.in in this case is a bad practice.